# How to limit the number of selections in a tkinter listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

Say I had a piece of code like this:

```
from tkinter import *

master=Tk()

ListBox1 = Listbox(master, selectmode=MULTIPLE)

for Count in range(0, 5):
    ListBox1.insert(END, Count)

ListBox1.pack()
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to limit the number of selected objects to something like 3 or 4. A quick google search and a read of the config options for `listbox` yielded no results and quite frankly I'm stumped as to how it could be possible to achieve these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I reviewed this question again today and ended up writing a solution for it, almost three years on:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.callback)
        for i in range(10):
            self.listbox.insert(END, i)
        self.selection = self.listbox.curselection()
    def callback(self, a):
        if len(self.listbox.curselection()) > 3:
            for i in self.listbox.curselection():
                if i not in self.selection:
                    self.listbox.selection_clear(i)
        self.selection = self.listbox.curselection()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This creates an instance of the data after each check, and then checks against the previous instance to see whether there are any differences, then removes those differences.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You have complete control over what is selected in the listbox. However, there's nothing built-in to support this so you'll have to write all the code that tracks the selection and disallows changing the selection based on some criteria. This would probably create a very confusing user experience since there's no way for the user to know that this standard-looking listbox has non-standard behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've been brainstorming ideas for it all afternoon and I keep coming back to just checking how many are selected when I try and move on and giving the user an error dialog. That's probably what it'll come down to but if I find a way to limit the number of selections easily I'll post it here for future users.